# Problem reading files in ntfs external hd from windows xp after installing ubuntu

Tags: windows, files, ntfs, compatibility

I am one of the guys that always used windows eventhough i hate it. A month ago i wiped out windows xp from my pc and installed ubuntu. I have an external hd and a second laptop which is left with windows xp.

After the ubuntu instalation i have used from pc without a problem the external hd and also added some files to it. From that point the pc sees everything but the laptop with the XP recognizes the external hd without seeing any files in it, only some directories with long arithmetic names and no real content inside.

Please help, it is/was my backup drive!

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears after you mount a ntfs partition in ubuntu, it becomes UNREADABLE in Windows. You can only reformat the partition. So i believe you already gave up[7months ago] in trying to recover your backup files.
I experienced this with somebodyelse notebook in 2011. Today in Ubuntu 12.10 when you connect an external NTFS HDD/usb memory stick, the disk remains READABLE to Windows. I think the problem occurs when a disk is separated in multiple different extension formats: Partition 0=ext4 , Partition 1=ntfs, Partition 3=Fat32, etc, so when you acces the other partitions inside Ubuntu, they somehow become Unreadable in Windows.
If what i said is wrong, please do explain what is really hapening and whats the solution? other than:"do not mount ntfs/fat32 partitions in Linux"